# Finding Substrings in Non-English Strings [Urdu Strings]

Tags: python, string, search, urdu

I wish to find substrings in strings that are in Urdu language. For example, suppose that I have a following string and substrings in the Urdu language:

```
fullstring = "آزاد دائرۃ المعارف، ویکیپیڈیا"

substring1 = "افریقی نژاد امریکی شہری حقوق کی تحریک (1955–1968) - آزاد دائرۃ ..."
substring2 = "Urdu English Translator حاصل کریں - Microsoft Store ur-PK"
substring3 = "ببر شیر - آزاد دائرۃ المعارف، ویکیپیڈیا"
substring4 = "اقوام متحدہ - ویکیپیڈیا"
substring5 = "واقعہ کربلا - آزاد دائرۃ المعارف"
substring6 = "Inaugural Address - Urdu | JFK Library"
substring7 = "دنیا میں امریکہ کے مقام کے بارے میں صدر بائیڈن کا خطاب - United ..."
substring8 = "ایران امریکہ کشیدگی: امریکی صدور اور جنگوں کی مبہم قانونی ..."
```

The objective is to search / find the words that are present in the **fullstring** in each of the **substrings** and then select the corresponding substring for further processing. Especially, the minimum words that are to be present in any substring should be **"آزاد دائرۃ"**.

In the above given examples, **substring1**, **substring3**, **substring4**, and **substring5** should be selected and returned **(True)**, whereas, the rest of the substrings should not be selected **(False)**.

I have written the following code to achieve the above given task:

```
fullstring = "آزاد دائرۃ المعارف، ویکیپیڈیا"
substring = "افریقی نژاد امریکی شہری حقوق کی تحریک (1955–1968) - آزاد دائرۃ ..."

# extract the part after the "-" part
s = substring.split("-")[1]
# remove any spaces if they are present
s = s.strip()

if s in fullstring:
   print("Found!")
else:
   print("Not found!")
```

The code is giving me **Not found!** response for all substrings. Whereas it should return **Found!** for *substring1*, *substring3*, *substring4* and *substring5*, and **Not found!** for all other substrings as given above.

Please help me in achieving the substring search task as described above.

Comment: please [edit] your question and add expected output for each substring, like "for substring1 - Found  for substring2 - ......" I have almost got the solution but don't know that is your expected output or not!

Comment: Edited as per your comment.

Comment: solved problem completely. Inform me if it is working for you or not. :)

Comment: Excellent. Can you please explain the code in the exception handler (try-except) part? Also, an up vote to the question will be greatly appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
fullstring = "آزاد دائرۃ المعارف، ویکیپیڈیا"
substring = "افریقی نژاد امریکی شہری حقوق کی تحریک (1955–1968) - آزاد دائرۃ ..."

# extract the part after the "-" part
s = substring.split("-")[1]
# remove any spaces if they are present
s = s.strip().replace(".","")

if s in fullstring:
   print("Found!")
else:
   print("Not found!")
```

Doing `striped` `s` is like `آزاد دائرۃ ...`  but you don't have `...` in `fullstring` so you're getting `Not found`.

Alternatively you can use `.find()` function like this :

```
fullstring = "آزاد دائرۃ المعارف، ویکیپیڈیا"
substring = "افریقی نژاد امریکی شہری حقوق کی تحریک (1955–1968) - آزاد دائرۃ ..."

# extract the part after the "-" part
s = substring.split("-")[1]
# remove any spaces if they are present
s = s.strip()

if fullstring.find(s)!=-1:
   print("Found!")
else:
   print("Not found!")
```

For all substring you can try this :

```
fullstring = "آزاد دائرۃ المعارف، ویکیپیڈیا"

substring1 = "افریقی نژاد امریکی شہری حقوق کی تحریک (1955–1968) - آزاد دائرۃ ..."
substring2 = "Urdu English Translator حاصل کریں - Microsoft Store ur-PK"
substring3 = "ببر شیر - آزاد دائرۃ المعارف، ویکیپیڈیا"
substring4 = "اقوام متحدہ - ویکیپیڈیا"
substring5 = "واقعہ کربلا - آزاد دائرۃ المعارف"
substring6 = "Inaugural Address - Urdu | JFK Library"
substring7 = "دنیا میں امریکہ کے مقام کے بارے میں صدر بائیڈن کا خطاب - United ..."
substring8 = "ایران امریکہ کشیدگی: امریکی صدور اور جنگوں کی مبہم قانونی ..."
allsub=[substring1,substring2,substring3,substring4,substring5,substring6,substring7,substring8]

for a in allsub:
    try:
        s=a.split("-")[1].strip(". ").strip()
    except IndexError:
        s=a.split("-")[0].strip(". ").strip()
    if fullstring.find(s)!=-1:
        print("Found!")
    else:
        print("Not found!")
```

Output :

```
Found!
Not found!
Found!
Found!
Found!
Not found!
Not found!
Not found!
```

I have created the list of all substring as `allsub` and checking as what you are doing. Additionally, I have done the `try-except` because in some substring there is no `-` and we selecting second element of list. So, sometimes it through errors. But if we use `try-expect` then it will execute `except` part rather than throwing error.

Comment: Unfortunately, same answer "Not found!".

Comment: I have tried the code that you had suggested. BTW, I cannot find the .find() function in your suggestion?

Comment: @user.1234 Sorry! my bad, I edited check it.

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: `fullstring.find(s)` is this what you have tried? I think you are confused. I have added complete code in last edit check it. If you are getting that error then, you must have changed `fullstring` into list by doing split or somethings... @user.1234 if you're getting error then just do copy/paste my code and test.

Comment: Inconsistent output. Please check your code against each substring that I have given in the question.

Comment: Are you asking for all subsubstring? Sorry, I have thought for just one! Okay I will check and edited my question. @user.1234 it is working fine for that one substring right?

Comment: @user.1234 and additionally there is some language/character barrier, I am confused, I personally haven't found `آزاد دائرۃ` this in full string also.

Comment: I think there should be something related to character encoding? utf8? I don't know much about how to do that part.

Comment: Your characters are already in unicode so you don't have to do that!

Comment: `s = substring.split("-")[1]` you don't have `-` in your `substring8` then how can you select second element of that `substring8.split("-")`?

Comment: @user.1234 please post your expected output! For each substring.

Comment: Edited as per your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
fullstring = "آزاد دائرۃ المعارف، ویکیپیڈیا"

substring1 = "افریقی نژاد امریکی شہری حقوق کی تحریک (1955–1968) - آزاد دائرۃ ..."
substring2 = "Urdu English Translator حاصل کریں - Microsoft Store ur-PK"
substring3 = "ببر شیر - آزاد دائرۃ المعارف، ویکیپیڈیا"
substring4 = "اقوام متحدہ - ویکیپیڈیا"
substring5 = "واقعہ کربلا - آزاد دائرۃ المعارف"
substring6 = "Inaugural Address - Urdu | JFK Library"
substring7 = "دنیا میں امریکہ کے مقام کے بارے میں صدر بائیڈن کا خطاب - United ..."
substring8 = "ایران امریکہ کشیدگی: امریکی صدور اور جنگوں کی مبہم قانونی ..."
allstrings = (substring1, substring2, substring3, substring4, substring5, substring6, substring7, substring8)
for a in allstrings:
    try:
        s = a.split("-")[1]
    except:
        s = a
    s = s.strip().replace(".", "")
    if s in fullstring:
       print("Found!")
    else:
       print("Not found!")
```

Output:

```
Found!
Not found!
Found!
Found!
Found!
Not found!
Not found!
Not found!
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for your reply. An up vote to the question will be appreciated.